# What is the official term of a plane flying under another plane to avoid radar?

Tags: radar, flying-in-formation

I was watching the news and, just now, learned that the Russians used a "trick" by flying a fighter plane under a cargo plane to Syria and successfully avoided radar detection for the fighter plane.

I wanted to learn more about this method (a Wiki article, for instance) but failed to find anything. So do the experts here know what this term is called, if there even is one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could an aircraft 'hide' in the aircraft shadow of another aircraft without being detected or noticed?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2381/could-an-aircraft-hide-in-the-aircraft-shadow-of-another-aircraft-without-bein)

Comment: Not a duplicate. The other answer is not about terminology.

Comment: This is not yet defined; invent one!

Comment: @BogdanWilli - pretty much all stuff has already been...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My copy of "EW 101: A First Course in Electronic Warfare" calls it "**formation jamming**".

[image]

Mind you, an operator of a radar with non-cooperative threat recognition capability will at least suspect something is wrong (although not from all aspects and ranges).

Answer (score 2):

If two aircraft are flying one above the other, they are flying in *stacked* formation.

[image: 12 Aircraft stacked formation]

12 Aircraft stacked formation SOP of 303 Bombardment Group, from 303rdbg.com

Of course, it is about flying, with nothing said about radar deception. This technique was used in B-17 combat boxes in WWII, where aircraft squadrons were stacked at multiple altitudes. One advantage of this tight box like formations was that they presented the anti-aircraft gunners with smaller target.